# How to (randomly) filter data.table based on other data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two data.tables, the main one DT 30M rows 15 cols and a small one sampleUsers 50k rows 1col.
I am trying to filter the big DT based on a random sample of unique users that I put into sampleUsers.
`DT[sampleUsers]` `merge(DT,sampleUsers)` `join(DT,sampleUsers, by = "userID", type = "inner")` all don't work for me cause they throw an error like:

```
Error in  in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. [...]
```

DT looks like:

```
head(DT)
   userID       time       refURL
1:      1 1396914606             
2:      1 1397002826             
3:      1 1397050230             
4:      1 1397158818             
5:    100 1397028490 facebook.com
6:    100 1397028498 facebook.com
```

sampleUsers looks like:

```
head(sampleUsers)
                userID  myID
1: 1000089045463267792  8948
2: 1000089045463267792 28029
3: 1000226029643951569 22077
4: 1000488257652897256 41877
5:   10012190558163229  8065
6: 1001364147664198715 11842
```

In DT there are approx. 10Mio unique IDs (that occur multiple times because of different timestamps. All I want to do is sample 50.000 unique Users and all their entries in DT.

Sorry if it sounds way to trivial but I just can't find a solution.
Help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Actually the normal way to do it is the right way to do it =)

Thanks a lot for the great `data.table` package - works wonderful.

Solution is almost the same as Ricardo Saporta suggested but with a focus on unique users:

`DT[.(sample(unique(userID), sampleSize, replace_T_or_F)), ...]`

Answer (score 1):

set the `allow.cartesian` flag to `TRUE`, ie:

```
  DT[sampleUsers, allow=TRUE]
```

---

However, the cartesian join cannot exceed 2^31 rows (2.1 billion rows).
Note that `(30e6 * 50e3) > 2^31`

You have two options.

(1) If you can disregard duplicate IDs, use

```
  unique(DT, by=key(DT)) [sampleUsers]  # by=key(DT) is default, but I like to use it for clarity
```

(2) Chop up sampleUsers into parts

```
 DT[sampleUsers[1:k], allow=TRUE]
 DT[sampleUsers[k:nrow(sampleUsers)], allow=TRUE]
```

---

Aside from the specific technical issue, if your goal is to sample your users, why not just use:

```
DT[.(sample(userID, sampleSize, replace_T_or_F)), ...]
```

the specific IDs sampled will be the first column in the output

Comment: Still Error as "join would result in more than 2^31 rows. which I dont get, since in my understanding should be somewhere around 5Mio rows (50k users with 100 timestamps each).

Comment: `2^31` is a machine limit. What is `dim(DT)` and `dim(sampleUsers)`

Comment: `dim(DT) [1] 37563321 15`

`dim(sampleUsers) [1] 50000 2`

Comment: Problem is I can't disregard duplicate IDs, cause I need all info in the other columns behind the duplicate IDs. (timelog data). Thus Option 1 and `DT[.(sample(userID, sampleSize, replace_T_or_F)), ...]` does not work. Option 2 would someday get me to the result, but I would need to chop it up in  approx 500 pieces which doesnt look like the right approach.